# Google Glass - set of live cards on click of another live card

Tags: google-glass

I want to display a set of live cards on click of another live card. Or maybe create a bundle of live cards.
Is it possible? I read somewhere that cardscrollview cant be used for live cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "live card" is simply a card that sits to the left of the Glass clock screen, which can be displayed using an existing layout (using `RemoteViews`) or with high-frequency direct rendering. So, it doesn't make sense to talk about live cards in other contexts outside of that part of the timeline, like responding to a tap or inside a bundle.

What you want to do is create an immersion (activity) that starts when you tap your top-level live card. This immersion can host a `CardScrollView` that displays the cards that you want in your bundle. These aren't live cards, but they can be views/layouts that have whatever content that you want, since you create them directly in your activity.